# Where can I find Magento Connect Manager for Magento 1.9.1

Tags: attributes, ce-1.9.1.0, magento-connect, magento-connect-manager

Please tell me How to go on Magento Connect Manager. I want to add a Banner Slider on Magento 1.9.1.0

Comment: I go to system but i could not find any magneto connect.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `system->Magento connect->Magento connect manager`  or

you can directly go to magento connect by following url (assuming magentohost is your magento root )

http://magentohost/downloader/

Comment: When i go to system then i could not find any magento connect option ??

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure what is actually you are asking for. This question is going to be closed anyways.

If you are unable to find `Magento Connect Manager` from adminside, then this is how you can find it.

1. Login into magento admin section in your application with your username and password
2. Use `System > Magento Connect > Magento Connect Manager` from your admin main menu.

[image]

3. You will enter into following page. Use proper username and password and there it will lead you to the Magento Connect Manager page.

[image]

4. Now use magento connect manager wisely. ***[Refer this for more details](http://www.magenmarket.com/news-and-blog/how-to-install-magento-themes-using-the-magento-connect-manager.html)***

Comment: I can not find any option of magento connect in system option. Please tell me how i find magento connect option ??

Comment: if you can find the above links inside admin section, then your admin section misses magento core codes. You need to consider a proper re-installation. This option is present in default in CE itself

Comment: Default in CE means ???? Where is this Option ??

Comment: ce means Community Edition.  What I mean by option is, the menu that you can see in the first image is actually available by installation. So it is not available means, you have some severe problem with your installation

Comment: Please tell me how to install CE in magento. Mention steps ??